# Let's encrypt giving error "Your connection is not private"

Tags: mysql, ssl, nginx

I am using let's encrypt SSL from past 4 months on my site which is hosted on nginx web server and it was working properly using HTTPS but today it suddenly starts giving an error that "Your connection is not private".I didn't change anything on the web server.only one thing I did that I connected my site database remotely on my PC using Mysql workbench.When I tried to connect my server database locally on my PC first time it asked something that **connection was unauthenticated without complete reading by mistakenly I clicked on ok**.Is this action affected my site privacy?How should i solved this issue

Comment: Let's Encrypt certificates expire after 90 days, so I'd suspect that's all that has happened. The "Your connection is not private" screen typically gives an error code or explanation as to what the reason is. Check it.

Comment: In chrome go to security tab and see what the certificate error says, https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTdbv.png